# how to spend ordinals/inscriptions?

Tags: taproot, wallet-import, ordinals

so, i have some sats with ordinals and brc20 tokens in them. useless. might as well treat them as ordinary btc.

question is - **how do i spend them?** ie send them to a btc address?
unisat wallet wont allow me to transfer my 'inscription balance' for fear of ordinals being lost.
jeesus who cares? thats exactly what i am after.

address type is **Taproot (P2TR) (m/86/0/0/0/0)**  I have some sats in it

i tried importing the priv key into other wallets - shows empty balance

Comment: Are you sure the derivation path is m/86/0/0/0/0 and not m/86'/0'/0'/0/0?

Comment: m/86'/0'/0'/0/0

Comment: imported the seed here https://bitmask.app/#/wallet